# Type of a value when defined in ghci vs when in script

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am a beginner in haskell and while reading about types, I observed the following and not able to understand the reason for it.
If I define the following values in the script

```
x = 2
y = x + 3
```

And now i check for their type, I get the following

```
*Chapter4> :t x
x :: Integer
*Chapter4> :t y
y :: Integer
```

If I change the definition of y from `y = x + 3` to `y = x + 3.1` and again check for type, I get this

```
*Chapter4> :t y
y :: Double
*Chapter4> :t x
x :: Double
```

But if instead I define the variables x and y using `let` in GHCi, in the following way,

```
*Chapter4> let x = 2
*Chapter4> let y = x + 3
```

Now i check for types and get this:

```
*Chapter4> :t x
x :: Num p => p
*Chapter4> :t y
y :: Num a => a
```

And now I change the definition of y again to `y = x + 3.1` and check for type I get this now :

```
*Chapter4> :t x
x :: Num p => p
*Chapter4> :t y
y :: Fractional a => a
```

So why this difference in behavior ? Is it something to do with 'let' ?

Comment: It has to do with the type defaulting rules: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#type-defaulting-in-ghci

Comment: Essentially `Num p => p` is more general than `Integer` or `Double`, since it fits any numeric type, but also less efficient. The REPL defaults to being more general, while scripts default to be more efficient. You can turn on/off the defaulting rules to have the same behavior, if you wish. Alternatively, always provide a type when you define a variable e.g. `*Chapter4> let x :: Integer ; x = 42`.